# System.getProperty("user.dir") anomaly in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

In my current project settings, I have configured Eclipse to place the compiled .class files in the /bin directory.

My puzzle is that, when I run the application via the IDE and get it to print the current working directory (System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir")) I expect the console output to be /bin - instead the value printed is the projectRoot folder (without the /bin suffix).

If I were to navigate to the /bin folder directly, and execute my java class, the current working directory is printed as I expect it to be. What I would like is the Eclipse IDE to behave similarly.

Any ideas as to why I am observing this disparity? I have gone through many project build settings, but cannot seem to find anything that would cause this anomaly.

Kind regards,
Dinuk

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Eclipse, the **working directory** defaults to the project directory.
You can [change this in the run properties](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-executionArgs.htm)
(`Project->Properties->Run/DebugSettings->Edit->Arguments` tab, at the bottom of the page).

**Edit:** Actually, the easiest way to get to it is `Run->Open Run Dialog->Arguments` tab.
It's been a while since I used Eclipse.

From an example of **[Eclipse Setup New Project](http://apps.sourceforge.net/mediawiki/sprite2d/index.php?title=Eclipse_Setup_New_Project)**

[alt text http://apps.sourceforge.net/mediawiki/sprite2d/nfs/project/s/sp/sprite2d/a/ae/EclipseNewProjectDebugArguments.jpg](http://apps.sourceforge.net/mediawiki/sprite2d/nfs/project/s/sp/sprite2d/a/ae/EclipseNewProjectDebugArguments.jpg)

Comment: And if I were VonC, I'd add an appropriate screenshot.

Comment: @mmyers: Thank you so much - I already spent 5 minutes trying to figure what could be causing this, and was afraid I would end up spending the best part of an hour looking for a hidden config setting.

Thank you for the prompt response  - I'll try to post a more interesting question next time :-)

Comment: @mmyers: all right, all right, just gimme a minute ;) +1, by the way

Comment: No, really, that's not the way I meant it. I meant that if I were you, and if I (being you) were posting an answer to this question, I (being you) would include a picture. I didn't mean that if I were you, I (being you) would go and add a picture to mmyers's post. Thanks for adding it, though. :)

Comment: (I'm assuming it illustrates what I said; flickr is blocked by the proxy server here.)

Comment: @mmyers: yes, I figured you meant it the way you just described. I just wanted to tease you a little bit, hence my tongue-in-cheek comment ;)

Comment: darn, flick blocked (just like for me at work, except I am posting this from home). I will check if I find a more accessible illustration.

Comment: ... and done (feel free to revert any change you might find inappropriate or not in the spirit of your original answer)