# Java - "user.dir" property with respect to command line\IDE execution

Tags: java

I am using `System.getProperty("user.dir")` as the entry point (absolute path) in which any other file (and directory) traversal is relative with respect to the entry point.

The `user.dir` property has different values whether the program is invoked from the command line, or by the IDE (as expected).

What is the best practice to insure that the `user.dir` property will be "independent" in the execution environment?

**Update:** if you are using Eclipse for your IDE, check [System.getProperty("user.dir") anomaly in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722003/system-getpropertyuser-dir-anomaly-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of the `user.dir` and similar properties is, that it is dependent on the execution environment.

So the answer would be: don't

What you can do though in eclipse is to edit the run configuration to use a working directory that fits your needs. This will be available in other IDEs as well I guess.

Comment: so implicitly it means that one which develops using IDE must expect a different behavior when the program is invoked from the command line?

Comment: absolut. Note that eclipse (and I guess every IDE) lets you configure the directory used as user.dir / working directory.