# Change directory of eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration, filesystems, buildpath

How do I change my working directory from

> Desktop/EclipseEE.app/Contents/MacOS

back to

> /Documents/workspaceEE/MyProject

It was originally the latter. I was trying to fix an error, and I don't  know what I did that changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to change your workspace? If so, the do the following: *File -> switch workspace*

Comment: Not necessarily changing my workspace. I am still under this **/Documents/workspaceEE/MyProject** workspace. However, when I run this **System.getProperty("user.dir")**, it gives me this **Desktop/EclipseEE.app/Contents/MacOS** instead, which i don't  get.

Comment: have a look at the launch configuration, there you should be able to change the working directory. Have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/722003/system-getpropertyuser-dir-anomaly-in-eclipse)